# How can I automatically trigger the "Run" function in SPSS

Tags: python, automation, spss

I currently have a SPSS stream that is pulling information from a server and outputting a report to .xlxs

In order to trigger the stream I have to manually access SPSS and click on the "Run" button so the report is created.

The python script would be included into the execution board in SPSS.

I have unsuccessfully tried to create a python script that will generate this trigger and repeat the function over and over.

I am running with the issue that the scripts I am trying to use call for a prior action in order to trigger the automated click. The "Run" function would be the original action that would be repeated indefinitely

Can someone guide me on the right way to generate this script.

Comment: Could you give us a code sample to show us what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a production mode job and invoke it in your job stream?